# Why is my MySQL query hanging when doing an ORDER BY with a LIMIT of over 250?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my query. It works very fast. I have an index on movies.movieid, movie.title, collectors_collections.barcode, and collectors_collections.username (as well as indexes on other tables):

```
SELECT *
FROM collectors_collections
JOIN movieitemdetails ON collectors_collections.barcode = movieitemdetails.barcode
JOIN movies ON movieitemdetails.movieid = movies.movieid
JOIN barcodes ON collectors_collections.barcode = barcodes.barcode
WHERE (wishlist = 'NO' OR wishlist IS NULL) AND barcodes.type = 'movie' AND username = 'ethanwa'
ORDER BY movies.title LIMIT 250
```

As soon as I change the LIMIT to this:

```
ORDER BY movies.title LIMIT 251
```

I get a constant hang in the query that I can't recover from unless I kill it. What could be causing this and how can I fix it? Is there some setting I am missing? Some index? Something corrupt?

Comment: Hey Ethan, what the explain says to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out that the hanging was being caused by not allocating enough memory to MySQL, thus causing all of the tables to be sent to disk, which made it take FOREVER. Just increase some of the memory amounts in the MySQL settings solved my issue.

Comment: Now that you've solved that problem you can fix your query.  Replace * with just the fields you need.